# MYSQL JOIN query results

Tags: mysql

I have an old forum I built many years ago that i'm turning into a read-only section on the website. As an exercise in programming i'm attempting to cut down the amount of code used despite the ***terrible*** database design.

What I am trying to achieve is on the reply page: a single query to show the first post (stored stupidly on the 'topics' table) and then the rest of the posts from the 'replies table.

Abridged tables:

```
'replies'
topicID
posted_by
body
date_posted

'topics'
topicID
subject
body
posted_by
date_posted
```

The form I'm trying to get is:

Initial Post from 'topics' followed by replies sorted by `date_posted` (oldest first).

here's the query I've been fiddling with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
r.body, r.posted_by, r.date_posted, t.body, t.date_posted, t.posted_by, t.subject
FROM
replies r
LEFT JOIN topics t
    ON r.topicID = t.topicID
WHERE
r.topicID = 2372
ORDER BY
t.posted_by DESC,
r.date_posted DESC
```

Has anyone got any ideas on how to tweak this to get my desired scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UNION query should provide the data you're looking for:

```
SELECT topicID, subject, body, posted_by, date_posted
FROM topics
WHERE topicID = 2372
UNION
SELECT r.topicID, t.subject, r.body, r.posted_by, r.date_posted
FROM replies r
    INNER JOIN topics t ON r.topicID = t.topicID
WHERE t.topicID = 2372
ORDER BY r.date_posted DESC;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, this is excellent. It does almost everything I wanted. Up until the `ORDER BY` where there is an error. I'll have to fiddle with it and see what i can do :)

Edit: I just dropped the `r.` alias and it worked ^^

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. As an alternative, you could wrap the second part of the UNION query with parenthesis, in order to apply the sorts only to the replies.